# Delete the remainder of the line after current word in VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to delete the text following the word the cursor is currently over at. E.g.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
     ^ the cursor is here
The quick 
        ^ the desired result
```

`eD` is quite close to what I would like to accomplish but it removes the character the cursor is over at too. `<C-U>` does the exact job but from the cursor to the beginning of the line.  Is there any combination which does the same forward?

Is there any other way to accomplish this than by creating another key mapping? There are quite a few shortcuts in vim so avoiding creating another one would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in NORMAL mode, here are a couple of solutions.

First solution:

```
wDD
```

Explanation:

1. Move one word forward
2. Delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line
3. Delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line

Second solution:

```
f<space>D
```

Explanation:

1. Move to first occurrence of `<space>` to the right
2. Delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about. Thank you!

Comment: And what about insert mode? Any other thoughts that combining the wDD with `<C-o>`?

Comment: It looks like there is no equivalent of `CTRL-U` for killing to the end of line in INSERT mode (similar to `C-k` in emacs).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

1. jump after word with `w`
2. then delete the rest of line with `d$`
3. remove skipped space after the word with `x`

So:

```
wd$x
```

Comment: And the `d$` can be simplified to `D`.

Comment: This is similar to `eD`. I have to remove the spaces instead of reinserting the char under the cursor. It's a workaround, but I hope VIM can do exactly what I want.